# Editing  grub to add XP boot menu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, backtrack

I have 2 Harddisks one of 40 gb and second is 200 gb.

In the first harddisk I was having 2 installations of XP. In the second harddisk I have installed backtrack then Ubuntu, so that is making a total of 4 OS available.

After installing linux, I am missing the XP entries to boot into. While there exists nothing in the menu.lst file (/boot/grub/menu.lst).

How can I edit the menu.lst to get the XP entries with the Ubuntu and Backtrack while booting?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open up Terminal and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

It will automatically search for the OSes on the system, and add them to the GRUB boot menu. No editing needed.

By the way, the GRUB config can now be found at:

```
/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If you need more information on how to configure GRUB, check out this [Ubuntu community article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).